# Can't hide location's port with nginx

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx, location

I'm trying to set up a domain for my node project with nginx (v1.5.11), i have succesfull redirected the domain to the web, but i need to use 3000 port, so now, my web location looks like `http://www.myweb.com:3000/` and of course, i want to keep only "www.myweb.com" part like this: `http://www.myweb.com/`

I have search and try many configurations but no one seems to work for me, i dont know why, this is my local nginx.conf file, i want to change `http://localhost:8000/` text to `http://myName/` text, remember that the redirect is working, i only want to "hide" the port on the location.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;


      server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
            proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/ http://myName/;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```

pd. I'm trying to fix it on my local windows 8 machine, but if other OS is required, my remote server works on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thanks you all.

Comment: Appears that your proxy_pass points to same localhost:8000 that your server listens to.
Change listen port to 80.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your `server` block:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

E.g.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

[Documentation reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect).

You should also change server_name to `myName`. `server_name` should be your domain name.

You should also be listening on port `80`, and then use proxy_pass to redirect to whatever is listening on port `8000`.

The finished result should look like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  www.myweb.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      }

      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
      }
    }
}
```

Comments were removed for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding the port during proxying needs these two lines in server body:

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

The conf is like:

```
server
{
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
access_log off;
}
```